# How to give elevation information to a polygon feature class using existing TIN file ? (geological mapping)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, dem, elevation, tin

I'm an ArcGIS 10.1 user.

My issue: I have a printed form of a map which depicts geological bodies being surface rock occurence. Additionaly, there are elevation contour lines. I digitized the map by creating a polyline feature class which includes an elevation field (double), a point feature class which includes an elevation field (double) representing the highest spots and a polygon feature class which includes a rock type field (text).
At the moment, I have created a TIN file using the elevation shapefiles (polyline and point as I mentioned). After that, I applied TIN to Raster and used this for a topographic cross-section.
An idea came to mind which is: I'd like to see rock types in my DEM. My polygon feature class does not include any elevation information. How could I give elevation information to my polygon f.class? Ask me for more details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could drape your geological polygons on the elevation surface you created to make them 3D.

Two ways in 3D Analyst are Interpolate Shape and Add Surface Information.

For an explanation of both see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000005m000000

Comment: Thanks for the answer mpianka. I'm planning to apply this. However, I doubt if this is what I'm looking for. I'll let you know.